# using file tags on OS X and windows

Tags: macos, windows, finder-tag

I use file tags in OS X 10.9.3 and I love it.

However, I store and access many of the same files on an external drive that I also access with a Windows computer.

Is there a way to see or search for those tags in Windows? I currently don't see anything under the "Tag" or "Label" attributes on Windows for files that I have tagged in OS X.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using mac software on other hardware.

Comment: @Rob The asker wants to know how tags/labels can be shared on a drive which is accessed both by OS X and Windows

Comment: How exactly do you mount/access the shared drive from OS X and from Windows? Which filesystem format are you using?